# How do i get object keys that include non enumerable properties from prototype chain

Tags: javascript

Right now this is my understanding of Javascript Objects...
    var a = {};

```
Object.defineProperties(a, {
    one: {enumerable: true, value: 'one'},
    two: {enumerable: false, value: 'two'},
});
a.__proto__ = {three : 'three' };

Object.keys(a); // ["one"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a); // ["one", "two"]
for (var i in a) console.log(i); // one  three
```

so

```
Object.keys(a);
```

Returns object's own keys that are also enumerable.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a); // ["one", "two"]
```

Returns object's own keys including non enumerable.

```
for (var i in a)
```

Returns object's and it prototype chain, only enumerable keys,

So how do you get non enumerable keys from prototype chain?

Code::

```
var  o = {a:1};

Object.defineProperty(o,'b',{configurable:true, enumerable :false, value:2,writable: true });

o.__proto__ = {c:3};

Object.defineProperty(o.__proto__,'d',{configurable:true, enumerable :false, value:4,writable: true });

Object.keys(o); // ["a"] -only self nonenum props.
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o); // ["a", "b"] -only self including enum props.
for (var i in o) console.log(i) // a c  -only enum props including from proto.
```

Comment: [MDN: Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: i edited questions a little , basically how do i get d

Comment: Reopen the question, as the linked question doesn't answer this.

Comment: OK, let's link a different one :-)

Comment: i guess it's a duplicate